# Unexpected token ) in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs, canjs

I am learning canjs and trying to retrive the data. As I am beginner I have wrote my whole code in one file.

This is my canjs file:

```
 Players = can.Control({
init: function(){
    this.element.html(can.view('view/players.ejs',{
        players: this.options.players
    }));
  }
})


Player = can.Model({
  findAll: 'GET /players'
},{});

var PLAYERS = [
 {


"id" : 1,
"name" : "Dipesh",
"rank" : 2,
"score" : 2000,
"__v" : 0

},{

"id" : 2,
"name" : "Aakanksha",
"rank" : 3,
"score" : 3920,
"__v" : 0
}];

can.fixture('GET /players', function(){
  return [PLAYERS];
});
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.when(Player.findAll()).then(
   function(playersResponse){
    var players = playersResponse[0]


     new Players('.player', {
        players: players

    });
  });
});
```

This is my ejs template:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
   <% list(players, function(player){ %>
     <li class="player" <%=(el)-> el.data('player', player) %>>
      <%== can.view.render('playerView.ejs', {
                player:player

            }) 
        %>

    </li>
<% }) %>
```

While running the file, it shows an error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )** in jquery.

But how is it possible? I dont change anything in jquery.

Comment: it's talking about your code, not jquery library :D

Comment: may be the error also mentioned about line number where its appearing..?

Comment: @DemoUser Its pointing to jquery library. I dont even open it

Comment: Post a screenshot of the console showing the error if you dont understand how to describe it : )

Comment: Where you link your file to jQuery, remove that link and use this one `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` ....does the issue still occur?

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes it still showing the same error

Comment: Can you make it online and provide us a link (URL) so that we can see exactly what is happening

Comment: This is my program http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=i0xFmpb649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be missing something over here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(Player.findAll()).then(
        function(playersResponse){
            var players = playersResponse[0];

            // Try to add a semicolon (;) at the end of playersResponse[0]
            //Hope this should help you

            new Players('.player', {
                players: players

            });
        });
});
```

**Update: Try to add a semicolon (;) at the end of playersResponse[0]. Hope this should help you.**

Comment: Just curious, what makes you say that?

Comment: Oh yeah, most definitely so. I was just curious how you knew it was in this bit of code

Comment: I am learning from here.  (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/diving-into-canjs--net-25105) 
nothing is given in that block in above page

Comment: Try to add a semicolon (;) at the end of playersResponse[0]. Hope this should help you.

Comment: Do it and let me know.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi It showing same error in players.ejs line number 8

Comment: okay, what is view/players.ejs ? check weather this is accessible or not?